# Android Studio: How to import java class from outside the project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, package

I'm working on an android game that requires a server. We've set up a git in which there are three folders: Client, Server and Shared:

Client contains the Android-Studio project.
Server contains an Eclipse project which is our server and database.
Shared contains java classes that I would like to use in both the Eclipse and Android-Studio project.

In Eclipse I successfully loaded the files from Shared by importing them as "file system". (It created a package and everything works great)
In Android-Studio, I can't find a solution that doesn't require me to copy-paste the classes in the project. The aim here is to have those file at only one location as they're susceptible to change but must me identical in both the projects... So those solutions don't fit my needs.

I'm looking for something like a way to link files from outside the project. (I managed to link libraries from inside the project already but not from outside)

Comment: 1) Publish common code as a .jar and make it a dependency. 2) Make a symlink from your project to your common folder. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Comment: That would be a great solution but the common code is supposed to change often. It is going to be modified a lot by different people. I guess we could publish it as a new jar every time but that's not very convenient.
(We're freshmen in engineering school, so we have no idea what we're doing haha :p)
Thank you for your answer anyway :).

Comment: Then symlink is your best choice.  Good luck!

Comment: Hey! I looked further into it, it's a great idea. It might cause some trouble on different OS but I'll keep that in my head. My teachers got me another solution that I'm going to use though, check it out :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution that might not be optimal but at least in my case it solved the problem.

In Android-Studio:
Create a folder called something like "CommonEclipseAndroid" following a path similar to this one: project/Android/app/src/main/java/com/example/myapplication/CommonEclipseAndroid
Paste the code you need to use in both project inside this folder.

In Eclipse:
Right click on your project: Properties > Java Build Path > Source > Link Source and choose the folder we've just created.

Now your projects use the same code. You only need to modify it once for both projects and there's no risk of error.

Hope I helped :).

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution is to copy the desired java files into your project structure. Of course, you may have to change package names manually.

Comment: Kinda frustrating if this is the best way of doing things. It makes it hard to be able to, for example, contribute to the library. But it does seem to be the easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the shared folder as a module .
go to file> new> import module
Now use the same imported folder in eclipse as well.

Comment: I had already tried that but Android-Studio is expecting a project!
"Specify location of the Gradle project or Android Eclipse project"
I assumed that it was the wrong option but maybe I have to make that common code a different project? (As of now it's just a folder with a bunch of class files)

Comment: this may not be a perfect solution but you can create a eclipse project that contains only the Java classes and then import it to the studio

Comment: Hmm, whatever eclipse project I try to import it doesn't work. I think it's looking for an Android project. I'm not creating a new android project just for a few class files. Thank you anyway, it was worth the try :).

Comment: okay, but if its not a problem with your server code you can create a android project with only java classes for shared files